# Customize title in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have some trouble with customize **FullCalendar**. Default title in **FullCalendar** its 'h2' with **month**, **year** and **prev**, **next** buttons.

I need to transform 'h2' in separate elements (p with year separately and p with month same);
And also I need change default view **prev month** and **next month** buttons to buttons with that month name.

I will be glad to any help.

Below is my code: (Month name in source is not English.)

```
var monthNames = ['Січень','Лютий','Березень','Квітень','Травень','Червень','Липень','Серпень','Вересень','Жовтень','Листопад','Грудень'];
var calendarDate = new Date()
var monthNum = calendarDate.getMonth();
var prevMonth = monthNames[monthNum - 1];
var nextMonth = monthNames[monthNum + 1];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        firstDay: 1, /* первый день  недели */ 
        defaultView: 'month',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
        },
        viewRender: function (view, element) {
            var monthNames = ['Січень','Лютий','Березень','Квітень','Травень','Червень','Липень','Серпень','Вересень','Жовтень','Листопад','Грудень'];
            var currentMonth = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').month();
            var customMonth = monthNames[currentMonth];
            $('.fc-prev-button, .fc-next-button').click(function(){
                prevMonth = monthNames[customMonth - 1];
                nextMonth = monthNames[currentMonth + 1];
            });
        },
        monthNames: ['Січень','Лютий','Березень','Квітень','Травень','Червень','Липень','Серпень','Вересень','Жовтень','Листопад','Грудень'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Січ.','Лют.','Бер.','Квіт.','Трав.','Черв.','Лип.','Серп.','Вер.','Жовт.','Лис.','Груд.'],
        dayNames: ["Неділя","Понеділок","Вівторок","Середа","Четвер","П'ятниця","Субота"],
        dayNamesShort: ["НД","ПН","ВТ","СР","ЧТ","ПТ","СБ"],
        buttonText: {
            prev: prevMonth,
            next: nextMonth
        },
    });
});
```

images [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTFfE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEjOq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the title empty and then inside your viewRender function, you can do this:

```
   viewRender: function(view, element){

   $('.fc-toolbar .fc-center').append('/* inside this, you can append any elements you need for your title */');   

    }
```